# Every ﬁnite group G that has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup is solvable.

Tags: normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Theorem:  Every ﬁnite group $G$ that has a normal Sylow 2-subgroup, i.e., with $n_{2}(G) = 1$    is solvable. (let $n_{p}(G)$ be the number of Sylow p-subgroups of $G$)

I proof the following:

"Let $P$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup.

Then $|P|=2^n$ and $|G|=2^n.m$ with $(2,m)=1$.

We have $n_{2}(G) = 1$. Therefor $P  \triangleleft G$ (because the condition $n_p(G) = 1$ is equivalent to saying that the Sylow p-subgroup of G is a normal subgroup.)

So, we have $1 \triangleleft P  \triangleleft G$.

To prove $G$ solvable, I will prove $G/P$ and $P/1=P$ solvable.

- $|G/P| = \frac{{|G|}}{{|P|}} = m$ is an odd number. Therefor $G/P$ solvable. (Because Theorem Feit-Thompson: Every odd order groups are solvable)
- $|P|=2^n$ ??? ..."

How to prove "$P$ solvable"?

My problem is that $|P|=2$ or $|P|=2^n$. (If $|P|=2$ then I  can prove.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $p$-groups are nilpotent, hence solvable. If you want induction, prove that the center is nontrivial, hence either $P$ is abelian (hence solvable), or $P/Z(P)$ has order strictly smaller than $P$ and hence solvable by induction.

Comment: So... you can invoke the Odd Order Theorem, but you don’t know $p$-groups are solvable? Weird.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.